# Compatibility EV3 software with NXT brick - known limits?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, ev3

Lego says I can I use the new software to program old NXT bricks:

> Q: Is EV3 backwards compatible with NXT hardware?
>
> A: Yes. You can program your NXT intelligent brick using the new EV3 software. However not all software features are supported by the NXT intelligent Brick. You cannot program your EV3 programmable brick with the NXT Software.)

Are there any known limits programming the NXT bricks? I often had problems with *MINDSTORMS NXT* under Mac OS X and would like to replace it if possible.

Comment: You can try the iPad version NXT-G.
More stable than osx version.

Comment: iPad has no USB and doesn't support bluetooth. Even if NXT-G was available, how would it connect to a NXT brick?

Answer (score 5):

EV3 has no support for the Light Sensor, just the Color sensor.  There is a Raw Sensor that can be used to create a Light Sensor MyBlock.  That MyBlock can then be used to create the various WaitFor, Loop, and Switch blocks using the Logic form of those blocks.

Then there is the calibration problem.  The Color Sensor block in calibration mode does not work on the NXT brick.  The EV3 can also program around that using file operations.

Finally, there is the memory problem. The new firmware leaves a bit less memory available on the NXT. The programs still need to be managed carefully to avoid using up all the memory.

Yes, you can use EV3 software on NXT bricks.  In general it is very easy.  There are some issues.

Answer (score 1):

EV3 software cannot connect to the NXT 2.0 brick through Bluetooth, only by USB. One can only hope that this is a bug and will be fixed.