# How do I get the Mindstorm EV3 software to recognize an NXT brick via Bluetooth?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, nxt, ev3-g, bluetooth

I'm trying to program my NXT brick via the EV3 software over a Bluetooth connection.

I can connect it via USB (although that too failed initially, but has since been resolved; not sure why) but I'd really like to do it via Bluetooth as I could with the NXT 2.1 software.

How do I get the EV3 software to recognize my NXT brick over Bluetooth?

Here is a copy of the connection area in the EV3 software showing that the NXT brick is available via USB but not Bluetooth:

[image: EV3 communications center]

And here is the same NXT brick available in the NXT 2.1 software:

[image: NXT 2.1 communications center]

Comment: A screenshot of the lower right corner of the EV3 software running on your PC/Mac would help.  There is a collapsible panel there that should list EV3/NXT(s) connected.  Also, the NXT has to be ON.

Comment: Update: it now connects via the USB cord but not via Bluetooth even though I can connect on the same machine with the old NXT software.  I'll include a screenshot when I get a chance.

Comment: Could you get a chance? Or have you been able to solve the problem by yourself? If so, please share with us what you learned.

Comment: **Update:** It will now recognize via USB but not via Bluetooth.  I'm not sure what changed.  I've updated the question to target Bluetooth only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Communicating with the NXT from the LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 software is not supported.

From http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/support/faq/:

> 3.10 Is the LEGO® MINDSTORMS® EV3 Home Edition Software backward-compatible with NXT Hardware?
>
> Yes. You can program your NXT Intelligent Brick using the new LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Home Edition Software. However, not all Software features are supported by the NXT Intelligent Brick.

It does not explicitly mention Bluetooth, but it is one of features that is not supported.

References:

- [Compatibility EV3 software with NXT brick - known limits?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2339/compatibility-ev3-software-with-nxt-brick-known-limits)
- http://robotsquare.com/2013/07/16/ev3-nxt-compatibility/

Comment: That's unfortunate.  It looks like Lego is no longer supporting the NXT software on Yosemite so Mac users will no longer have Bluetooth as an option for NXT.

Comment: Does Lego no longer support NXT 2.0 at all? I am running Mac OS X 10.15 (Catalina) and the EV3 software can't detect my NXT 2.0 using USB.

Comment: LEGO officially stopped supporting NXT in 2015, however the original NXT programming software is still available on the official LEGO MINDSTORMS web page. The original NXT programming software and EV3 desktop programming software are both 32-bit, so cannot run on macOS 10.15. The new EV3 programming software based on Scratch does not work with NXT. So the only way to program NXT on macOS 10.15 is with 3rd party software such as NXC/NQC or leJOS.